In Fallout: the role-playing game, is the gauss rifles supposed to use the "small guns" or "energy weapons" skill?
In the 2d20 Fallout ttrpg by Modiphus, the gauss rifle is listed under small guns, which makes sense to me, as it fires projectiles. In the description of the "energy weapons" skill, however, it calls out the gauss rifle as a weapon that uses the skill. Which is the correct skill when using a gauss rifle, "small guns", or "energy weapons"?

Amusingly, you can't even base the choice on the video games; the older 2D isometric games (FO2 & FO:Tactics) used Small Guns, the later 3D games used Energy Weapons. Guessing that discrepancy made it through editing into the tabletop game.

Gauss rifles should use Small Guns
The official errata document for Fallout (available here) only mentions Gauss weapons once, but has this to say under the changes made on 6 September 2022:

• p.44: Remove gauss weapons from both Big Guns and Energy Weapons on the Skills Summary.

This indicates the rifle and any other gauss weapons (not that any appear in this book) are intended to use the Small Guns skill, as reflected by the skill listed with the weapon on page 95. That change hasn’t been reflected in other places in the rules, annoyingly - the errata doesn’t make any changes to the examples in the skill description, hence the confusion.
